# Flutter GetX - how to implement a loading screen that check the token

Tags: flutter, router, flutter-getx

So this is the scenario:

I build an app that the first route or the first thing to do is check with a API REST a verification of a token that I already have on localsorage. If the token is valid, proceed to the home page route, if don't we need to redirect them to login screen. All this is async. I already try to get this working adding a route like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/',
          page: () => const AppPage(),
          middlewares: [AppPageMiddleware()],
        ),
        GetPage(name: '/login', page: () => const LoginPage()),
        GetPage(
            name: '/operator', page: () => const OperatorHomePage(), transition: Transition.zoom),
      ],
    );
```

As you can see, I load a AppPage that the only thing that they do is show the loading spinner. The middleware called AppPageMiddleware uses this:

```
  GetPageBuilder onPageBuildStart(GetPageBuilder? page) async {
    // here I perform the call to the API and wait for the response.
    // If the API response is true, I need to save the response
    // and redirect to OperatorHomePage

    print('Bindings of ${page.toString()} are ready');
    return page!;
  }
```

But I have an error here because I can't add async.
Maybe this is not the best way to do this, if you can suggest me another way, I will appreciate so much. Sorry, I'm new with GetX.